# define a part of column series to index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'col': ['a11 aaa','a121 aaaa','a3333 adfdf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i want to set index Similar ['a11','a121','a3333']

```
print(df)
```

Comment: Something like `df['col'].str.split(expand=True).set_index(0)`?

Comment: Please add the required output to your question.

Comment: Or normally simpler than I want to return the first characters from this data frame as the data frame index before space character(' ').

Comment: df = ( col = ["a11 aaa", "a121 aaaa", "a3333 adfdf"] , index = ["a11", "a121", "a3333"], )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

```py
import pandas as pd 
data = {'col': ['a11 aaa','a121 aaaa','a3333 adfdf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.index = df['col'].apply(lambda line: line.split(' ')[0]).tolist()
df
```

#### Option 2

```py
import pandas as pd 
data = {'col': ['a11 aaa','a121 aaaa','a3333 adfdf']}
indexes = map(lambda line: line.split(' ')[0],data['col'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=indexes)

df
```

#### Output

```
      |  col
a11   | a11 aaa
a121  | a121 aaaa
a3333 | a3333 adfdf
```